# Extracting just hour and min from utcTimeStamp row from SQL table

Tags: sql, sql-server

So I have a situation where I know the procedure will query out a row that is formatted in UTCStampTime fashion. THe problem I am running into is when I want to build a query on the two CTE's I have need to be returned only when the time is equal on each CTE variables. But the problem is that my query only is looking at the last 10 minutes and I only want the two rows to be equal when the minutes of the utcTimeStamp columns are the same.  here is my query that i am running.

```
   GO
    declare @fqnLine1Downtime varChar(4000)
   declare @fqnLine1Throughput varChar(400) 
    declare @fqnLine2Downtime varChar(4000)
    declare @fqnLine2Throughput varChar(400) 
    declare @parameter1Line1 varChar(4000) 
   declare @parameter2Line1 varChar(4000)
   declare @parameter1Line2 varChar(4000) 
   declare @parameter2Line2 varChar(4000)  
    declare @server varChar(200)
   declare @timeStart datetime
   declare @timeEnd datetime


   WITH 
CTEThroughputLine1(Time, Amount, ThroughputLine1)
  AS
 --Define the query
(   
    SELECT CONVERT(VarChar(20),utcTimeStamp) as Time, shortName as 

      ThroughputLine1, valueAsInt as Amount 
        From dbo.History(@fqnLine1Throughput, @parameter2Line1, @timeStart, 
    @timeEnd, @server)
     ),

   CTEThroughputLine2(ThroughputLine2, Amount, Time)
   AS
   (
    Select shortName as ThroughputLine2, valueAsFloat as Amount,
     CONVERT(VarChar(20),utcTimeStamp) as Time
    From dbo.History(@fqnLine2Throughput, @parameter2Line2, @timeStart, 
     @timeEnd, @server)
     )
```

---

```
   select * from CTEThroughputLine1 as Line1 inner join 
  CTEThroughputLine2 as Line2 on Line1.Time = Line2.Time
```

I have purposefully not include the setting of the variables because it includes private info on my Company. I think this should be enough to tackle the problem. Please help or point out hints.

Comment: Please share your table's DDL, or at least tell us what data type `utcTimeStamp` is. Also, you may want to look at [`DATEPART()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174420.aspx): `DATEPART(mi, Line1.Time) = DATEPART(mi, Line2.Time)`.  - You're using MS SQL Server, aren't you? Please re-tag your question with your RDBMS product.

Comment: I did not mean "re-tag with RDBMS"! What I meant was: Remove the "microsoft" tag and add the tag for your RDBMS, e.g. "sql-server 2008" or "mysql".